# Argument of type X is not assignable to parameter of type Y (although there's inheritance)

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to find out exactly why the code below doesn't compile:

```
type IEntityName = 'model1' | 'model2' | 'model3'

class Model {
    id: string

    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id
    }
}

class ModelChild1 extends Model { }
class ModelChild2 extends Model { }
class ModelChild3 extends Model { }

const MAP = {
    model1: ModelChild1,
    model2: ModelChild2,
    model3: ModelChild3
}

function getModel(entityName: IEntityName) {
    return MAP[entityName]
}

function doSomethingElse<T extends Model>(model: new () => T) {

}

function doSomething(entityName: IEntityName) {
    const model = getModel(entityName)
    doSomethingElse(model)
}

doSomething('model2')
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=34&pc=22#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgogO2AS1AOQIYFtoF4oDkWA9gCYQA2AjAVAD6EnkUBMtDRZlAzAQFB8AxhQwBnUVACyXClADefKEqjJSALiijgAJ2QIA5gOVRBxBFu0BXQcGLaAFKo0W9%20gJTzFx5cAAWyUQA6VSh8VS8lAF8%20aKERcSkZAGF-ClIqKAgAD2AIBFIJaWZ5KGjhMULk1NIWTJy8gsTiuVK4iqbKFOQ07jrc-Mrm1qEzLSkAQQAFUM9jJkoqDSLO6qoAGgioedYlqu6ajbmZbl3mLp6YgQAzSwQbZDMofQhgZYp7PJR0bAgNeCRUCBMDgPApjNoXpZtAgJpMANqfQHAiAAXUufBudxQj1IxAAysQcH5XHAKKIIAAeAAqfQag0oAD57NsNAgIAB3KD2Dy4BlQKmgzbozH3HH4wkvfwGD4A744P6IL5An6C4ymczALYyGbPV4yGVK5FuTa4glEqX6Unk5kyY2xU0S4nSzjMNhuIA)

I don't understand the problem and more important, I don't understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the constructor parameter type, it should be:

```
new (id: string) => T
```

Comment: Is this the only way to handle this? What if I have 500 parameters?

Comment: You can do `function doSomethingElse(model: typeof Model)` if you don't need the generic parameter.